# why nrow(dataframe) and length(dataframe) in r give different results?

Tags: r

I have a ordered data frame and want to know the number of the last row.

```
data_ranking <- reduced_data[order(reduced_data$outcome,reduced_data$hospital,na.last=NA),]
nobs <- nrow(data_ranking)
```

gives me different results of

```
data_ranking <- reduced_data[order(reduced_data$outcome,reduced_data$hospital,na.last=NA),]
nobs <- length(data_ranking)
```

I would like to understand why is that. It seems that `nrow`gives me the answer I'm looking for, but I don't understand why.

Comment: `length(df)` returns the number of columns, i.e. is equivalent to `ncol(df)`. Since a data.frame is two dimensional, `length` can only measure one, and columns is what whoever wrote it went with.

Answer (score 11):

data frames are essentially lists where each element has the same length.

Each element of the list is a column, hence `length` gives you the length of the list, usually the number of columns.

`nrow` will give you the number of rows, `ncol` (or `length`) the number of columns.

The obvious equivalence of columns and list lengths gets messy once we have nonstandard structures within the data.frame (eg. matrices) and

```
 x <- data.frame(y=1:5, z = matrix(1:10,ncol=2))
 ncol(x) 
 # 3
 length(x) 
 # 3


 x1 <- data.frame(y=1:5, z = I(matrix(1:10,ncol=2)))

 ncol(x1) 
 # 2
 length(x) 
 # 2
```

Comment: Curious that for a matrix, like your `matrix(1:10,ncol=2)`, `length` returns not rows _or_ columns, but the total number of elements (here 10). It's not a very intuitive function...

Comment: @alistaire - that's because a matrix is simply a vector with dimensions. It has length 10, nrow 5 and ncol 2. It makes sense in that way. E.g., look at how a matrix can be created using basic functions - `structure(1:10, .Dim = c(5L, 2L))`

Comment: @thelatemail That explains it, thanks! There really is reasoning behind the function, but it's certainly not what a beginner would expect.