# How to fix a loop of Function that stops prematurely before going through the entire dataframe

Tags: r, function, loops

So I am running a function that takes average levels of infection on a plant, and works out how much the plant has been infected over time. It's called the Area Under the Disease Progression Curve. The function works, which is good, I am now trying to create a loop to work this out for each plant and store it in a dataframe. However the loop stops way before it should?

The function works as it can be used by hand, that is to say putting the Plant_ID in one at a time, but the loop seems to stop before getting through the whole data frame. I'm really lost has to why it is stopping

The Function is as follows:

```
audpc <- function(df,plant_ID){
  #subset the df so that only rows with the tree.ID of interest are kept
  df <- subset(df, Plant_ID == plant_ID)
  # assign time.period and disease.severity vectors for use below
  time.period <- df$Week
  disease.severity <- df$Upper_percentage
  #n is the length of time.period
  n <- length(time.period)
  #meanvec is the vector
  #that will contain the mean percent infection
  #it is initialized containing -1 for all entries
  #this sort of initialization is sometimes useful
  #  for debugging
  meanvec <- matrix(-1,(n-1))
  #intvec is the vector that will contain the length of
  #   time between sampling dates
  intvec <- matrix(-1,(n-1))
  for(i in 1:(n-1)){
    #the ith entry in meanvec is replaced with the
    #   mean percent infection
    #between sample time i and sample time i+1
    meanvec[i] <- mean(c(disease.severity[i],                   
                         disease.severity[i+1]))
    #the ith entry in intvec is replaced with the length
    # of the time interval between time i and time i+1
    intvec[i] <- time.period[i+1] - time.period[i]
  }
  #the two vectors are multiplied together
  # one entry at a time
  infprod <- meanvec * intvec
  #the sum of the entries in the resulting vector
  #   gives the AUDPC
  sum(infprod)
}
## end of function
```

and then the broken loop is below

```
#

## make an "output" dataframe to store AUDPC values
out <- subset(DF1, Week == 31) #we want each tree.ID just once
#add a column of NAs to replace with AUDPC values
out$AUDPC <- rep(NA, length(out[,1])) 

#run the function on a loop for each tree.ID in your output df
for (i in 1:length(out[,1])){
  tree.ID <- DF1$Plant_ID[i] #assign tree.ID for use in audpc func

  #n = number of observations (timepoints) of PM infection
  n <- length(subset(DF1, Plant_ID == tree.ID)$Week)
  #if n > 2, run the output func and put the value into the AUDPC column 
  # of your output df that corresponds to the current tree.ID
  out$AUDPC[which(out$Plant_ID == tree.ID)] <- ifelse(
    n > 2, audpc(DF1, tree.ID), NA)
}

## remove NA values
out.na <- na.omit(out)
dim(out)
```

A subsect of my data is below via dput, it stops after 9 observations on my computer?

```
DF1<- dput(structure(list(Plant_ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L), .Label = c("1", 
"10", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", 
"108", "11", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", 
"118", "119", "12", "120", "121", "123", "124", "125", "126", 
"127", "128", "129", "13", "130", "131", "132", "134", "135", 
"136", "137", "138", "139", "14", "140", "141", "142", "143", 
"144", "146", "147", "148", "15", "151", "152", "153", "154", 
"155", "156", "157", "159", "16", "162", "166", "168", "169", 
"17", "170", "172", "173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", 
"179", "18", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", "185", "186", 
"187", "188", "19", "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", "195", 
"196", "198", "199", "2", "20", "200", "201", "202", "203", "204", 
"205", "206", "207", "208", "209", "21", "211", "214", "215", 
"218", "22", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", 
"228", "229", "23", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", 
"236", "237", "238", "239", "24", "240", "241", "242", "243", 
"244", "245", "246", "247", "248", "249", "25", "250", "251", 
"252", "253", "254", "255", "256", "257", "258", "259", "26", 
"260", "261", "262", "263", "264", "266", "267", "268", "269", 
"27", "271", "272", "273", "276", "277", "278", "279", "28", 
"280", "281", "282", "283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "288", 
"289", "29", "290", "291", "292", "293", "294", "295", "296", 
"297", "298", "299", "3", "30", "300", "301", "302", "303", "304", 
"305", "306", "307", "308", "309", "31", "310", "311", "312", 
"313", "314", "315", "316", "317", "319", "32", "320", "321", 
"322", "323", "324", "325", "326", "327", "328", "329", "33", 
"330", "331", "332", "333", "334", "335", "336", "337", "338", 
"339", "34", "340", "341", "342", "343", "344", "345", "346", 
"347", "348", "349", "35", "350", "351", "352", "353", "354", 
"355", "356", "357", "358", "359", "36", "360", "361", "362", 
"363", "364", "365", "366", "367", "368", "369", "370", "371", 
"372", "373", "374", "375", "376", "377", "378", "38", "380", 
"382", "386", "387", "388", "389", "39", "390", "391", "392", 
"393", "394", "395", "396", "397", "398", "399", "4", "40", "400", 
"401", "402", "403", "404", "405", "406", "407", "408", "409", 
"41", "410", "411", "412", "413", "415", "416", "417", "418", 
"419", "42", "420", "421", "422", "423", "424", "425", "426", 
"427", "428", "429", "43", "430", "431", "432", "433", "435", 
"436", "437", "438", "439", "44", "441", "442", "444", "445", 
"448", "451", "452", "453", "454", "456", "457", "458", "459", 
"46", "460", "461", "462", "463", "464", "467", "468", "47", 
"470", "471", "475", "476", "477", "478", "479", "480", "481", 
"482", "483", "486", "487", "49", "492", "493", "494", "496", 
"497", "499", "5", "50", "500", "501", "502", "503", "504", "505", 
"506", "507", "508", "509", "51", "510", "511", "512", "516", 
"517", "518", "519", "520", "521", "522", "523", "524", "525", 
"526", "527", "528", "529", "530", "531", "532", "533", "534", 
"535", "536", "537", "539", "54", "541", "543", "544", "545", 
"546", "547", "548", "55", "551", "552", "553", "554", "555", 
"556", "557", "558", "559", "56", "561", "562", "563", "564", 
"565", "566", "567", "568", "569", "57", "570", "571", "572", 
"573", "574", "575", "576", "577", "578", "579", "58", "580", 
"581", "582", "584", "585", "586", "587", "588", "589", "59", 
"590", "591", "592", "593", "594", "597", "599", "6", "60", "601", 
"602", "603", "604", "606", "607", "608", "609", "61", "610", 
"611", "612", "613", "614", "615", "616", "617", "618", "619", 
"62", "620", "621", "622", "623", "624", "625", "626", "627", 
"628", "629", "63", "630", "631", "632", "633", "634", "635", 
"636", "637", "639", "64", "640", "641", "642", "643", "644", 
"645", "646", "647", "648", "649", "650", "651", "652", "653", 
"654", "658", "659", "66", "665", "666", "667", "67", "671", 
"674", "675", "676", "678", "68", "680", "682", "683", "685", 
"686", "689", "69", "690", "697", "698", "7", "70", "702", "703", 
"704", "705", "706", "707", "708", "71", "710", "711", "713", 
"714", "716", "717", "718", "719", "72", "720", "721", "723", 
"724", "726", "727", "728", "729", "73", "730", "731", "732", 
"733", "734", "735", "736", "737", "738", "739", "74", "740", 
"741", "742", "743", "744", "745", "747", "748", "749", "75", 
"750", "751", "752", "754", "755", "756", "757", "758", "759", 
"76", "760", "762", "763", "764", "765", "766", "767", "768", 
"769", "77", "770", "772", "775", "776", "777", "778", "779", 
"78", "780", "79", "8", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", 
"87", "88", "9", "90", "91", "93", "94", "95", "97", "98", "99"
), class = "factor"), Upper_percentage = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.42857142857143, 
2, 0, 0, 0.15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 
0.444444444444444, 1.66666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 1.14285714285714, 
0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.33333333333333, 2.6, 2.63636363636364, 
6.81818181818182, 0, 0, 0.1, 5.73684210526316, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.285714285714286, 
6, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
0, 0.5, 2.875, 0, 0, 13.6666666666667, 21.5, 0.6, 0.6, 8.2, 25.6, 
0, 0, 0.25), Week = c(26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 26L, 29L, 31L, 27L, 
29L, 31L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 27L, 31L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 
27L, 29L, 31L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 26L, 
27L, 29L, 31L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 27L, 29L, 
31L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 
26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 27L, 
29L, 31L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 
27L, 29L, 31L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 27L, 29L, 
31L)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame"))
```

There are 29 different Plant_ID codes in the example data so I should receieve 29 observations of an AUDPC score. Instead I receieve 29 observations but with most of them as NAs.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help with my problem and excuse me if i've been unclear anywhere!

Comment: I've just noticed my row numbers are not the same as my Plant_ID numbers, I beileve the loop is going to the 624 row number (Being the number of Plant_ID codes I have and then stopping! So If anyone knows an easy way to get the row numbers to match the Plant_ID numbers this may solve it?

Comment: (my idea here also did not work by the way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need the nrow function instead of the length function. See the post here for a discussion about the difference between the two functions:

[why nrow(dataframe) and length(dataframe) in r give different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305988/why-nrowdataframe-and-lengthdataframe-in-r-give-different-results)

EDIT
Actually, the error seems to be in your loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(out[,1])){
  tree.ID <- DF1$Plant_ID[i] #assign tree.ID for use in audpc func

  #n = number of observations (timepoints) of PM infection
  n <- length(subset(DF1, Plant_ID == tree.ID)$Week)
  #if n > 2, run the output func and put the value into the AUDPC column 
  # of your output df that corresponds to the current tree.ID
  out$AUDPC[which(out$Plant_ID == tree.ID)] <- ifelse(
    n > 2, audpc(DF1, tree.ID), NA)
}
```

You are iterating through i rows in your out dataframe. However, the first line in your loop is using the ith row of the df dataframe as a reference point. I think it should be using the ith row of your out dataframe. Change the first line in your loop to:

```
  tree.ID <- out$Plant_ID[i] #assign tree.ID for use in audpc func
```

Comment: Yes! I came to a similar conclusion just before you posted, although my attempt was much more due to trial and error of randomly changing things! Thanks! i've marked yours as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem comes from here, the beginning of your loop

```
for(i in 1:(n-1)){
```

You need to write:

```
for(i in 1:length(data.frame)) {
```

Obviously, data.frame would be the name of the dataset you are currently working with.

Let me know how it goes

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. That is part of my function which works, n-1 refers to the time period of infection. It's the loop below that is giving me hassle. Within the loop I've got for: `(i in 1:length(out[,1])){
  tree.ID <- DF1$Plant_ID[i]`  Which should account for the length of the dataframe correct? I have tried you suggestion but it sadly just broke the function?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your comments! I have discovered if I change

```
for (i in 1:length(out[,1])){
```

To instead go for the length, (as below) of the entire OG dataframe then it seems to work

```
for (i in 1:length(DF1[,1])){
```

But I do not really understand why this has worked, but there we are anyway!

Thanks again!